# The table does not have a primary key defined error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables that are basically link tables.

So one looks like this;

```
QueueId
TaskId
```

the two columns link to a `Queues` table and a `Tasks` table.

There is no primary key and i don't believe I need one.

I so try to import it into my `.EDMX` and I get the warning that

> the table does not have a primary key defined but that it's been inferred as a read only table.

Also, the table doesn't show up in the Diagram and there is no model created for it.

I added a primary key and then got errors in my code.

I deleted all tables and did it all again and still the same thing happens with this one table.

The second table that is virtually identical has the same error but does appear in the diagram.

How do I get the first table to show in the diagram and not be read only because I need to delete the associations from time to time.

Thanks

Comment: you should still put an identity column so each row will have its own identification. :)

Comment: @Dr.Stitch No you dont, I don´t know how to do it with data base first approach but in code first it is easy

Comment: @Dr.Stitch.  I tried adding an identity column that caused issues in the code.  I "could" go back and debug that, but this is a simple link table that doesn't require an identity.

Comment: @griegs do you have foreign keys to tables, which are linked with these tables? Entity framework designer should import them not as entities but as assiciations if everything is set up correctly. At least that's the behavior that I see in EF6. Edit: I mean, it creates an entity, but it is not visible in model designer, and there is no class for it.

Comment: @DmitryRotay, yeah that is the behavior I am seeing. However, how then in code can i delete the association given that a task can belong to multiple queues?  If the table is read only and I cannot access it in code then...

Comment: @griegs there should be two navigation properties on either side of the relation - `Task` has `ICollection<Queue>` and `Queue` has `ICollection<Task>`. To remove association between specific task and queue you either find queue and remove that thask from it's collection, or do the reverse. The former seems more logical, so you can even remove navigation property on `Task` side so it's not that confusing. Edit: I'm note sure how EF handles remove on only one side of relation, if there are both navigation properties - does it remove it on other side or not.

Comment: Yeah @DmitryRotay we just talked about that and came to the same conclusion.  EF is trying to be smart and I need to work with it and not against it.  Write this up as an answer and i'll accept

Comment: @griegs glad to confirm your finding. Good luck with it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework doesn't need association table in the model to work with it.

There should be two navigation properties on either side of the relation - `Task` has `ICollection<Queue>` and `Queue` has `ICollection<Task>`. To remove association between specific task and queue you either find queue and remove that thask from it's collection, or do the reverse.